# compare two dictionary extract key if matches

Tags: python, dictionary

Dictionary which saved in the test.json which saved as file is below

```
[
  {
    "applicationName": "Benz",
    "Code": 101,
    "Type": "Petrol",
    "Color": "White"
  },
  {
    "applicationName": "Tesla",
    "Code": 102,
    "Type": "Electric" ,
      "Color":"Blue"   },
    {     "applicationName": "BMW",   
     "notificationCode": 103,   
     "Type": "Petrol" ,   "Color":"Black"   } ]
```

if my input is `d = {'Code': 102}` then i need to extract `Type` and `Color` from the `test.json`

Code is below

```
import json
conf = json.loads(r'C:\users\Desktop\test.json')
sample = {}
if d['Code'] == conf['Code']:
   sample.update(conf['Type'])
   sample.update(conf['Color'])
```

Comment: Your JSON objects all exist within an outer array in your `test.json` sample, so as you have it written, `conf['Code']` would result in a `TypeError`, since you can't index a list with a string.

Comment: I think you have to use loop to compare all dictionaries.

Comment: Also, since you're reading from a file, you want `json.load`, not `json.loads`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember, your json is a list

```py
import json

import json

def locate(code: str):
    with open(r"C:\users\Desktop\test.json") as f:
        cars = json.load(f)
        for car in cars:
            if car["Code"] == code:
                return {"Type": car["Type"], "Color": car["Color"]}
        return None

print(locate(101))
```

for loop

```py
import json

def locate(d):
    with open(r"C:\users\Desktop\test.json") as f:
        cars = json.load(f)
        for i in range(0, len(cars)):
            car = cars[i];
            if car["Code"] == d["Code"]:
                return {"Type": car["Type"], "Color": car["Color"]}
        return None

print(locate({"Code": 102}))
```

you can also use `next`

```py
import json

def locate(d):
    with open(r"C:\users\Desktop\test.json") as f:
        cars = json.load(f)
        match = next((car for car in cars if car["Code"] == d["Code"]), None)
        return {"Type": match["Type"], "Color": match["Color"]} if match else None

print(locate({"Code": 102}))
```

Comment: can you do in normal for loo[

Comment: sorry, updated my answer to use d["Code"]